# how to create a statusbar like netbeans' statusbar by using swing?

Tags: java, swing, popup, toolbar

[image]

here is screenshot.  and how can I do it by using swing?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: `JProgressBar` is what you are looking for

Comment: @Sujay  as you see,I tried Blazze.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box solution for a system bar like that, but it's not hard do make something like that. 
It's just a panel (with right aligned Flowlayout) with a label ("Blazze (run)"), a JProgressBar showing the current progress, and a cancel button.

Add BorderLayout to your main content panel and add the systembar with orientation SOUTH.

If you don't understand the Swing layout concept, please be sure to read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

If you don't understand progress bars, read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html).

All you have to do afterwards is control the texts and visibility and so on.

---

Edit:

For the popup I would recommend using an undecorated JDialog or JWindow, with a TimerTask to make it visible/disappear after a given amount of time. But that depends on what you want to achieve. The default tooltip is for text (and simple HTML) only.

Comment: the Layout and progress bar are not the point, what I am looking for is the pop-uped panel above them.

Comment: @Leajon you should have mentioned that in the question... please see my edited answer

Comment: I will try undecorated JDialog. Thx! If I can make the dialog move(bind) with mainFrame, that will be cool.

Comment: I found the solution:http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CreatingPopUpComponents.htm